# C++ to Ruby: find substring in a string

Tags: c++, ruby

I learned Rails and now would like to expand my knowledge of Ruby.  So I'm doing some C++ exercises in Ruby.  Specifically I need to find if a substring exists in a string.  If it does I need it to return its starting index.  If it doesn't exist have it return -1.  I came up with a Ruby solution that's very similar to C++ and was wondering if there's a "better", more idiomatic solution in Ruby?

C++

```
int find(char str[], char sub_str[])
{
  int str_length = strlen(str);
  int sub_str_length = strlen(sub_str);
  bool match = false;

  for(int i=0; i<str_length; i++)
  {
    if(str[i] == sub_str[0])
    {
      for(int j=1; j<sub_str_length; j++)
      {
        if(str[i+j] == sub_str[j])
          match = true;
        else
        {
          match = false;
          break;
        }
      }
      if(match)
        return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Ruby

```
def find_sub_str(str, sub_str)
  match = false
  for i in 0...str.length
    if str[i] == sub_str[0]
      for j in 1...sub_str.length
        if str[i+j] == sub_str[j]
          match = true
        else
          match = false
          break
        end
      end
      if match == true
        return i
      end
    end
  end
  return -1
end
```

Comment: Ruby implements many generic `String`, `Array` routines of this sort directly as methods on the built-in classes. To learn idiomatic Ruby you will want to stretch out into some higher-level business logic - e.g. a routine that used this string matching to provide highlighting of terms in HTML.

Comment: Best bet is to pretend you don't know any C++, it will keep leading you astray.

Comment: You learned Rails but don't know Ruby? Then you don't know Rails, you only know how to configure parts of it.

Comment: `"I need to find if a substring exists in a string. If it does I need it to return its starting index."`. Did you read [the String documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html)? There are several paths to getting the information you need.

Comment: @theTinMan I forgive not using the core `index` method if the OP’s objective was an academic exercise (hence my answer’s intermediate solution). Though I strongly agree with you that Ruby should be learned *before* Rails.

Comment: Thanks for telling me what I know and don't know @theTinMan.  I learned Ruby to the extent that it's needed for Rails.  I can develop pretty advanced sites with RoR.  But reading a Ruby book I notice there is a lot of Ruby I have never used.  That's what I'm trying to learn with these exercises.  I am well aware that a substring function is built into Ruby.

Comment: Without Ruby there is no Rails. Rails, without an understanding of Ruby is a very steep learning curve, and is restricted to merely configuring things, not programming controllers, writing views, or defining the actions of models. Even the DSLs within Rails require a modicum of Ruby otherwise the syntax will make no sense, nor will using blocks. Once someone starts to understand Ruby they can actually become creative and productive. Without Ruby someone merely parrots what others have done.

Comment: I'd highly recommend NOT try to learn Ruby, a fairly high-level language, based on C++ exercises, which teach a fairly low-level language. C and C++ are closer to assembler than they are Ruby; Learning Ruby from Perl would be a closer match. I've written in them all, and the progression of the functionality of each language and how we think in them, leads to quite a gulf with C++ <==> Ruby. If you want to try that, I'd recommend thinking beyond searching for characters in strings by indexing -- that's assembler thinking and concentrate on higher functions. That's the gist of Andrew's answer.

Comment: @theTinMan, again, thanks for the positive and warm response and your deep understanding of what I do and don't know about Rails.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson the c++ way is `auto index = s1.find(s2);` no wrapper needed, gives -1 and everything OP wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don’t use `for` in Ruby, it just calls `each` and doesn’t introduce scope. So `for i in 0...str.length` becomes `(0...str.length).each do |i|`.
2. Higher-order functions are your friend! Using [`each_cons`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) & [`find_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_index) makes things much cleaner (study [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html), it’s home to many useful methods):

   ```
   def find_sub_str(str, sub_str)
     str.chars.each_cons(sub_str.length).find_index do |s|
       s.join == sub_str
     end
   end

   find_sub_str('foobar', 'ob')  #=> 2
   ```
3. Just use Ruby core’s [`index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-index) `:)`:

   ```
   'foobar'.index('ob')  #=> 2
   ```

Both #2 & #3 return `nil`, not `-1`, when there is no match. This is best because `nil` is falsey in Ruby.

Comment: +1. Also, using `each` helps sidestep the "Help! I've run off the end of the array" problems that indexing encounters too.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-index) method of `String`. It returns `nil` on failure to match, which is more idiomatic Ruby than returning -1.

```
 "SubString".index("String") # -> 3
 "SubString".index("C++") # -> nil
```

You could wrap it in a test that returns -1 for nil if you really wanted this behavior.

Comment: Really, really want it.

Comment: i detect c++ bashing, even though we have `auto index = s1.find(s2);` and in c++14 `"Substring"s.find("string");` - which , before you ask, [gives -1 on failure](http://ideone.com/tYTQyd).

Answer (score 0):

```
#how if we use this solution, it gets the job done in O(n)    

given_string = "Replace me with your code!"

chars_given_string = given.split('')

chars_of_substr = "ith".split('')

is_substr = false
ptr = 0

char_given.each do |i|
    if ( i == substr[ptr])
       ptr += 1
    else
       ptr = 0
    end
    is_substr = true if ptr == substr.length
    break if ptr == substr.length
end

puts is_substr
```